# Why can the Views Gantt module not find the DHTMLX Gantt JS library?

Tags: 7, views, theming

I am trying to use the [Views Gantt](https://www.drupal.org/project/views_gantt) module and getting nowhere fast.

The Status Report is complaining that it cannot find the dhtmlxgantt JS library in the libraries directory - despite my having checked its presence over and over.

Has anyone any ideas what I might be doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure the dhtmlxgantt JS library is located in: `sites/all/libraries/dhtmlxgantt` ?

Within that folder you should have extracted the original library which should have:
`sites/all/libraries/dhtmlxgantt/codebase` and `sites/all/libraries/dhtmlxgantt/samples`.

Also make sure the "dhtmlxgantt" folder name is all lower case.

Answer (score 0):

A typical explanation for this is that **if** you're using the older version in the 7.x-1.x branch (eg because there is no stable 2.x version yet) **then** you should use the older DHTMLX 1.3 library, which you can still download from this [DHTML Gannt](http://downloads.zdnet.com/product/2383-75867487/?d=1) link.